# How to get documents with fields that contains array with more than one value?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following index properties:

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": { "type": "text" },
      "place": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "home": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "work": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get all the documents that contain more than one value of `place` field.

For example, if the index contains the following 2 documents:

```json
{
    "content": "First content",
    "place": [
        {
            "home": "home_1",
            "work": "work_1"
        },
        {
            "home": "home_2",
            "work": "home_2"
        }
    ]
},

{
    "content": "Second content",
    "place": [
        {
            "home": "home_3",
            "work": "work_3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to write a query that gives us the first document (because it contains `place` field with an array of size 2).

I have tried:

```
"filter": {
            "script": {
                "script": "doc['place'].values.length > 1"
            }
        }
```

But I got error:

```
RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [filter].')
```

Comment: @Paulo answer which you have suggested will not work in this case because field type is `nested` and not `object`.

Comment: @SagarPatel thanks for highlighting this, i've reopened it

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/help-for-painless-iterate-nested-fields/162394 apparently it is not doable.
My bad for closing it, I should have red more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Using function_score**

You can add `exits` query and check if `home` field is available in each element of `place`. If it is available, then it will score with `1` and you can use `score_mode` to `sum` so if there are 2 elements, then the sum will be 2 and if there are 1 element then sum will be 1. Last you will set `min_score` to `2` so all documents which have scored 2 will come in response.

```json
POST counttest/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "place",
          "query": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "place.home"
            }
          },
          "score_mode": "sum"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "_score > 1 ? 2 : 0"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  },
  "min_score": 2
}
```

**Option 2: Using Script Field**

This will add new fields with value `true` or `false` and application side you can make the decision to show documents or not.

```json
POST counttest/_search
{
  "_source": "*", 
  "script_fields": {
    "new_place": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "params['_source']['place'].size() > 1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample Response:

```json
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "counttest",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ZXKc1oAB4onl0QH9hzaW",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "place" : [
            {
              "work" : "work_1",
              "home" : "home_1"
            },
            {
              "work" : "home_2",
              "home" : "home_2"
            }
          ],
          "content" : "First content"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "new_place" : [
            true
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "counttest",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ZnKv1oAB4onl0QH9HjaD",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "place" : [
            {
              "work" : "work_3",
              "home" : "home_3"
            }
          ],
          "content" : "Second content"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "new_place" : [
            false
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Option 3: Store count at index time** (**Best Solution**)

You can store a number of elements available in `place` field while indexing document itself. Once you store count with the document, it will be very easy to filter a document and it will not add load to response time.

**Sample Document**

```json
{
    "content": "First content",
    "place_count" : 2,
    "place": [
        {
            "home": "home_1",
            "work": "work_1"
        },
        {
            "home": "home_2",
            "work": "home_2"
        }
    ]
},

{
    "content": "Second content",
    "place_count" : 1,
    "place": [
        {
            "home": "home_3",
            "work": "work_3"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Query:**

```json
POST counttest/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "place_count": {
        "gte": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't give me the right results. For example Option 2: gives 2 documents instead of 1

Comment: Yes, **Option 2** will always give you total number of document and with that you will get new field  `new_place` which have either `true` or `false` value.

Comment: @SagarPatel could `post_filter` be used to remove the `new_place = false` items? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/filter-search-results.html

Comment: @CraigEddy No, You can not use `post_filter` as the script_fields are calculated during last fetch phase and it will be available for only requested document, means if size is set to 10 then only for that 10 documents. So when `post_filter` is applied that time `script_fields` not exits.